# How to make Perl die after declaring array with non-existent hash keys

Tags: perl

I'm declaring an array like this:

```
my @row = (
$discordances{$assay}{plate_pair},
$assay,
$discordances{$assay}{contigName},
$discordances{$assay}{start},
$discordances{$assay}{test_calls},
$discordances{$assay}{truth_calls}
);
```

but I want the program to die when I declare `@rows` using non-existent hash keys

right now, I'm using `use warnings FATAL => 'all'` & `use autodie ':all'` but neither of these is catching the error.  I have code later which is designed to catch a possible error, but I'm trying to keep this as short as possible for readability and ease of use, so I don't want to use that code to catch something which `use autodie ':all'` should already be catching.

How can I get Perl to die on such an array declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no warning here because it is perfectly legitimate to look up a non-existent hash key and get undef as the result and to have an array element be undef.

If you try to use any of the undef elements as a string or a number, at that point you will get a warning.

If that isn't good enough, you can explicitly check:

```
die "missing values" if grep ! defined, @row;
```

Comment: This could die even if the keys existed, but their corresponding value was `undef`.

Comment: "non-existent hash key" is a bug in my book.  My programs fail without definitions.  Nonetheless, thanks for your 1-line solution!

Answer (score 2):

There is [exists](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html). That should let you know whether there is something under the key, also if it is an undef, as in

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %the_hash = ( 1 => undef );

# (undef, undef)
my @arr1 = ( $the_hash{1}, $the_hash{2} );

# (undef)
my @arr2 = map { $the_hash{$_} } grep { exists $the_hash{$_} } qw(1 2);
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
my @arr = map { $the_hash{$_} } grep { exists $the_hash{$_} or die 'the message' } qw(1 2);
```

Is that it?

Answer (score 2):

At the expense of an extra pair of actions you can use core [Hash::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/Hash/Util.html) to lock the keys

```
use Hash::Util qw(lock_keys unlock_keys);

my %h = (k1 => 7); 

lock_keys %h;

my @ary = (3, $h{nokey}, $h{k1});  # dies; no problem w/o that 'nokey'

unlock_keys %h;                    # So you can modify it later
```

This example with a non-existing `nokey` goes down with

```
Attempt to access disallowed key 'nokey' in a restricted hash at ...
```

So remember to unlock keys after the array assignment if you need to be able to change them later.

Note that you may need `lock_hash_recurse`, to lock deeper keys as well. See docs.

---

These can be "absorbed" in a `do` block

```
my @ary = do { 
    lock_keys %h;
    my @ary_tmp = ( 3, $h{...}, ... );
    unlock_keys %h;
    @ary_tmp;          # returned
};
```

for some cleanliness and to make sure that unlocking isn't forgotten, but I am not sure whether it helps while it incurs extra expense of a data copy, and of creating an array (only to be discarded).